# Convert JQuery Animation to Javascript/CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to move a div left and increase the height and width by 100px. I could do this using JQuery but I was wondering how I will do it using JavaScript/CSS3?

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#div").animate({
        left: '250px',
        height: '+=100px',
        width: '+=100px',
    });
});
```

I'm using the translate function to move it

```
-webkit-transform: translate(100px,0);
```

But I'm not sure how to go about increasing the size.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: First question: What do you hope to achieve by switching to CSS3 animations?

Comment: This is more of a learning exercise.

Comment: The reason I ask is that there are times when using CSS animations is appropriate and times when they are not. Even if you CAN do it, you should step back and ask WHY you are doing it. Is this a popular thing? Is it the best way to get what I want done? Why is it the best way?

In general, I find that CSS animations are not much more performant than GSAP or Velocity animations, and they are always less reliable.

Answer (score 0):

How about [keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)?

```
@keyframes identifier {
  0% { width: 25%; height: 40%; }
  30% { width: 30%; height: 30%; }
  68%, 72% { width: 75%; }
  100% { width: 80%; height: 50%; }
}
```

---

One option is [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale):

```
transform:  scale(sx[, sy]);
```

to make 2x:

```
transform:  scale(2);
```

or 2x width, 3x height:

```
transform:  scale(2,3);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the size of my div is in percentages and I want to increase the size by a fixed amount, so I'm not sure how well scaling will work.

Comment: You mean, get the current % and then add or subtract a fixed %?